# Read data with multi delimiter in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ascii, csv

I have a input file which looks like this and has `"|"` as multi-delimiter :

````
162300111000000000106779"|"2005-11-16 14:12:32.860000000"|"1660320"|"0"|"2005-11-16 14:12:32.877000000"|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|"False"|"120600111000000000106776```
````

I can read this type of record with UDF as below :

```
inputDf = glueContext.sparkSession.read.option("delimiter", input_file_delimiter,)
             .csv("s3://" + landing_bucket_name + "/" + input_file_name)

udf = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: re.sub('"', '', str(x)))
new_df = inputDf.select(*[udf(column).alias(column) for column in inputDf.columns])
```

but when i get the input file as

```
000/00"|"AE71501"|"Complaint for Attachment of Earnings Order"|"In accordance with section test of the Attachment of Test Act Test."|"Non-Test"|"Other non-test offences"|"N"|"Other Non-Test"|"Non-Test
```

I am getting below exception while reading it, using the same UDF, my code fails at exact same location where i have mu UDF :

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfa' in position 66: ordinal not in range(128)

Any help on below will be great :
 - Optimized code to read both type of files , considering `"|"` as separator.
 - How my existing UDF can handle the second type of input records.

Comment: I doubt the error is being generated by what you think. The stacktrace says it has something to do with the Unicode symbol u'\xfa', which is _ú_, and is not present in what you show.

Comment: I have a very big file,can be in that file some where.

Comment: Saldy, we cannot reproduce your problem with the data you provided. Could you generate a minimal dataset that allows us to do just that?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by running in Python 2.x which has two separate types for string-like objects (unicode strings and non-unicode strings, which are nowadays simply byte sequences).

Spark will read in your data (which are bytes, as there is no such thing as plain text), and decode the lines as a sequence of Unicode strings. When you call `str` on a Unicode string that has a codepoint that is not in the ASCII range of codepoints, Python 2 will produce an error:

```py
# python2.7>>> unicode_str = u"ú"
>>> type(unicode_str)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> str(unicode_str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfa' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The recommended path is that you work with Unicode strings (which is the default string object in Python 3) all throughout your program, except at the point where you either read/receive data (where you should provide a suitable encoding scheme, so that you can decode the raw bytes) and at the point where you write/send data (again, where you use an encoding to encode the data as a series of bytes). This is called “[the Unicode sandwich](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)”.

Many libraries, including Spark, already decode bytes and encode unicode strings for you. If you simply remove the call to `str` in your user defined function, your code will likely work:

```py
#pyspark shell using Python 2.7
>>> spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("OFF")  # to hide the big Py4J traceback that is dumped to the console, without modifying the log4j.properties file
>>> from py4j.protocol import Py4JJavaError
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
>>> df = spark.read.csv("your_file.csv", sep="|")
>>> def strip_double_quotes_after_str_conversion(s):
...   import re
...   return re.sub('"', '', str(s))
... 
>>> def strip_double_quotes_without_str_conversion(s):
...   import re
...   return re.sub('"', '', s)
... 
>>> df.select(*[udf(strip_double_quotes_without_str_conversion, StringType())(column).alias(column) for column in df.columns]).show()
+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+---+--------------------+----+
|   _c0|    _c1|                 _c2|                 _c3|                 _c4|             _c5|_c6|                 _c7| _c8|
+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+---+--------------------+----+
|037/02|TH68150|Aggravated vehicl...|Contrary to secti...|Theft of motor ve...|Vehicle offences|  Y|Aggravated Vehicl...|37.2|
+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+---+--------------------+----+

>>> try:
...   df.select(*[udf(strip_double_quotes_after_str_conversion, StringType())(column).alias(column) for column in df.columns]).show()
... except Py4JJavaError as e:
...   print("That failed. Root cause: %s" % e.java_exception.getCause().getMessage().rsplit("\n", 2)[-2])
... 
That failed. Root cause: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfa' in position 78: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So, the solution to the experienced problem is simple: don’t use `str` in your UDF.

Note that Python 2.x will no longer be maintained as of January 1st 2020. You’d do well transitioning to Python 3.x before that. In fact, had you executed this in a Python 3 interpreter, you would not have experienced the issue at all.